# Add and edit content form in a pop up in drupal

Tags: javascript

Hi is there any modules available inorder to display the add content and edit content form in Drupal of all content type as a pop up. That is when i edit or add a content link it should display as a pop up.Plz suggest some solution without programmming.

Comment: Is Drupal Overlay module (default) is not fit your requirement?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan No, it isn't, not quite - see [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/492/16495) - it requires a bit of coding and OP doesn't want that, if we want to avoid conflicts in some situations. Of course, 
kiamlaluno♦ already posted all code needed, so...

Comment: @Mołot OK, Got it  :)

Comment: This add and edit form is for the authenticated role users